# How do you sort two arrays exactly the same?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

How would you go about sorting two arrays the same way?

```
hey = %w[e c f a d b g]
hoo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
hey.sort      #=> [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
hoo.same_sort #=> [4,6,2,5,1,3,7]
```

Comment: I am guessing this has something to do with the hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a try:

```
hey.zip(hoo).sort
=> [["a", 4], ["b", 6], ["c", 2], ["d", 5], ["e", 1], ["f", 3], ["g", 7]]

hey.zip(hoo).sort.transpose
=> [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], [4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a single sort, using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
sorted_indices = hey.each_index.sort_by { |i| hey[i] }
  #=> [3, 5, 1, 4, 0, 2, 6] 
hey.values_at(*sorted_indices)
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
hoo.values_at(*sorted_indices)
  #=> [4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7]
```

Comment: I knew you were going to appear and I knew you were going to do that.

Comment: @sawa, I figured that's how you'd do it.